# Prove $ α + β = β$ if and only if $αω ≤ β$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Here we have both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals. I need to prove that $ α + β = β\Leftrightarrow αω ≤ β$.

It seems that maybe the forward direction can be done by induction, but could someone please show me how should I do it? May I please ask how to prove this statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that if $\eta\leq\delta$, then there is a unique $\gamma\leq\delta$ such that $\eta+\gamma=\delta$.

Now, in the one direction, $\alpha+\beta=\alpha+(\alpha\cdot\omega+\gamma)=(\alpha+\alpha\cdot\omega)+\gamma = \dots$

In the other direction, recall that $\alpha\cdot\omega=\sup\{\alpha\cdot n\mid n<\omega\}$, so by induction if $\alpha+\beta=\beta$, we get that $\alpha\cdot n+\beta=\beta$ for all $n$, therefore $\alpha\cdot n\leq\beta$ for all $n$. What does that tell you about $\alpha\cdot\omega$?

Comment: As $\omega$ is the $sup$, once we done with the induction we con show that $\alpha\omega\le\beta$. But after doing search in my textbook I cannot find a way to do the induction. I have spent some time on it. So could you please write out explicity how exactly can I do the induction? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is really as simple induction as they can get. You should be able to handle that on your own.

Comment: Oh, I see. It is really trivial. Thanks a lot!